# Automatic switches for a 12 V LED with two separate power sources

Tags: led, switches, 12v

[image: My system, basically]I am converting a Mercedes Benz Sprinter van into an RV. I have a 12 V LED dome light (actually several) that activate when a door is opened, powered by the vehicle's power system (battery/alternator) I would like to tie that same light into the 12 V house system, without the two systems back feeding each other.

What is the best way to accomplish this?[Would oneof these work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V87nP.png)

Comment: A diode would do the job. But "best" depends on various other things we don't know about... A schematic of the set up would help.

Comment: What is " the 12 V house system"? Please give more informations and a schematic or drawing of the complete installation.

Comment: I would just connect it to the house system instead of the vehicle system.

Comment: Pics added, hope it helps clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If I just connect it to the house system it won't come on when I open a door. and if i only connect it to the vehicle, I won't be able to turn it on normally.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a DPDT switch which I think is what you meant to draw on your third sketch. Below is the schematics, I added a couple of diodes to protect from possible back current, their values would depend on the amount of current of the system, but those are not strictly necessary.

[image]

If the negative terminals of the battery/alternator and the house system are connected to each other, you could simplify it a bit by using a SPDT switch instead, by switching the positive pole only.

Alternatively if you want a solution that is more automatic, which will detect when the house system is off and switch automatically to use the battery/alternator and back once the house system has power again, you could use an *Automatic Switching Controller*, for example: [https://www.amazon.com/ROSEBEAR-Controller-Battery-Emergency-Automatic/dp/B08L32RHFX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L32RHFX) you can find them also on eBay and AliExpress, just pay attention to the combined current used by your domes, this example in the link is for maximum 10Amp load, that is the sum of the current of all the LED domes combined would need to be lower than 10Amp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my system I used schottky diodes. The battery output is modified with a sepic converter to keep the lights about the same brightness on or off line. Power from the house system is set at about 12.5 and the sepic is set for about 12.25. The power switchover is instantaneous and no blinks. If you use this solution parts will have to be sized appropriately.